# Animation onresume activity

Tags: android

There is a sliding animation between two activities. In `onCreate` method, I am using this:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

And `onResume` method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.slide_in);
    super.onResume();
}
```

**slide_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
   android:fromXDelta="100%p"
   android:toXDelta="0%p">
```

**slide_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
   android:fromXDelta="0%p"
   android:toXDelta="-100%p">
</translate>
```

The problem is: when I return back to the activity, it shows the same animation (right to left). I want to invert it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: because when you return back to Activity `onResume()` will get called!

Comment: yes.. so, how can i revert that effect from previous one?

Comment: in onPause() of second activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add two more animation file

slide_in_back:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" >
</translate>
```

slide_out_back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
   android:fromXDelta="0%p"
   android:toXDelta="100%p">
</translate>
```

call when starting activity:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

call on onBackPressed() method or after calling finish() in any activity:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_back, R.anim.slide_out_back);
```

Here is also a tutorial to look: [Link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/02/android-animation-switching-activity.html)

Hope this helped!